# Problem with the proof that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros for $\mathrm{Re}(s) = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

Almost every proof I read says that

> If $\zeta(s)$ has a zero of order $\mu$ in $1 + ai$ ($\mu \geq 0$) then
>   $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\; \epsilon \frac{\zeta'(1+\epsilon +ai)}{\zeta(1+\epsilon +ai)} = \mu $$

without spending a word to explain it.

Why is this so obvious? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

That has nothing to do with $\zeta$ in particular. For any holomorphic $f$ that has a zero of order $\mu$ in $z_0$, you can write $f(z) = (z-z_0)^\mu\cdot g(z)$ with a holomorphic function $g$ that satisfies $g(z_0) \neq 0$. Then $f'(z) = \mu\cdot(z-z_0)^{\mu-1}\cdot g(z) + (z-z_0)^\mu\cdot g'(z)$ and hence

$$\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \lim_{z\to z_0} \frac{\mu\cdot (z-z_0)^\mu\cdot g(z) + (z-z_0)^{\mu+1}\cdot g'(z)}{(z-z_0)^\mu\cdot g(z)} = \mu.$$